# React key error with react router dom 6.4 on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a key error in React in a subcomponent passed as an outlet with React Router Dom 6.4. Here, I am showing you the errors and various files to understand what I am doing wrong with the creation of this sidemenu with React DOM. If someone has an example with or without outlet or would be the best way to create a sidemenu with dropdown menu with a structure => File > Subfile > items ?
I need the better with functional react and hook ^^"

I test Nanoid for key.. but nope

App.tsx

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar'
import { Home } from './pages/Home'
import { Dashboard } from './pages/Dashboard'
import { Folders } from './pages/Dashboard/Folders'
import { Upload } from './pages/Dashboard/Upload'
import { JobView } from './pages/Dashboard/JobView'
import './App.scss'

function App() {

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path="/nav" element={<Navbar />}/>
      <Route path="login" element={<div>Login</div>}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
        <Route index path="upload" element={<Upload />}/>
        <Route path="folders/:folderId?/subs?/:subId?/jobs?/:jobId?" element={<Folders />}/>
        <Route index path="job" element={<JobView />}/>
        <Route path="search" element={<div>search</div>}/>
        <Route path="visual" element={<div>visual</div>}/>
        <Route path="personae" element={<div>personae</div>}/>
        <Route path="map" element={<div>map</div>}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<div>error 404</div>} />
  </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

Dashboard

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react"
import { Outlet, useOutletContext, useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { Modal } from "../../components/Modal"
import { useModal } from "../../useModal"
import { Sidemenu } from "../../components/Sidemenu"
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import './styles.scss'

import { Folders, Subfolder, Jobs } from '../Dashboard/Folders'

export type DataContextType = {
    foldersList: Folders[],
    isActiveFolder: (id: number) => void,
    isActiveSub: () => void,
    isActiveJob: (id: number) => void,
    isActiveCheckbox: (id: number) => void,
    //counterJobs:  (jobs: Folders[]) => number,
    toggle: () => void,
    handleModalContent: (e: string) => JSX.Element
  }

export function Dashboard() {

    const { folderId, subId, jobId } = useParams();
    const { isShown, toggle } = useModal();
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState<Folders | {}>({})

    const [foldersList, setFolderList] = useState<Folders[]>([
            {
                "id": 1,
                "color": "ff7c03",
                "name": "Bubble",
                "transcriptions": [
                    "8561ec02-b689-45e3-bb90-04bd07ee5df1"
                ],
                "subfolders": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Jobs",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "isChecked":  false,
                        "jobs": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Toto",
                                "isActive": false,
                                "isChecked":  false
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "Marketing",
                                "isActive": false,
                                "isChecked":  false
                            },
                        ], 
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Marketing",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "isChecked":  false,
                        "jobs": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Bubble Jobs",
                                "isActive": false,
                                "isChecked":  false
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "Bubble Marketing",
                                "isActive": false,
                                "isChecked":  false
                            },
                        ], 
                    },
                ], 
                "isActive": false,
            },
           //etc...
    ]);

    const counterJobs = useCallback( (jobs: Folders[]) => {
        let countJobs = 0
        jobs.map( (folder) => { if (folder.jobs.length > 0) { countJobs += folder.jobs.length }} )
        return countJobs
    }, [foldersList])

    const isActiveFolder = useCallback( (id: number) => {
        return setFolderList(
            foldersList.map( folder => {
            if (folder.id === id) {
                folder.isActive = !folder.isActive 
            }
            else folder.isActive = false
            return folder
        })
        )
    }, [foldersList])

    const isActiveSub = useCallback( () => {
        return setFolderList(
            foldersList.map( folder => {
                folder.subfolders.map( sub => {
                    if (subId) {
                        if ( sub.id === parseInt(subId) ) { sub.isActive = !sub.isActive }
                        else sub.isActive = false
                    }
                })
            return folder
        })
    )
    }, [foldersList])

    const isActiveJob = useCallback( () => {
        return setFolderList(
            foldersList.map( folder => {
                folder.subfolders.map( sub => {
                    if (subId) {
                        if ( sub.id === parseInt(subId) ) { 
                            sub.jobs.map( job => {
                                if (jobId) {
                                    if ( job.id === parseInt(jobId) ) { job.isActive = !job.isActive }
                                    else job.isActive = false
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            return folder
      })
    )
    }, [foldersList])

    const isActiveCheckbox = useCallback( (id: number) => {
        console.log("toto ", Date.now());
        
        return setFolderList(
            foldersList.map( folder => {
                folder.subfolders.map( sub => {
                    if (subId) {
                        if ( sub.id === parseInt(subId) ) { 
                            sub.jobs.map( job => {
                                if (jobId) {
                                    if ( job.id === parseInt(jobId) ) { job.isChecked = !job.isChecked }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            return folder
        )
    )
    }, [foldersList])

    const handleModalContent = useCallback( (id: string | null) => {
        let content = '';
        if (id) {
            content += id
        }{}
        console.log(content);
        return <div>{content}</div>
    }, [toggle])

    const addProject = useCallback(
        (newProject: Folders) => setFolderList([...foldersList, newProject]),
        [foldersList, setFolderList]
      );

    const handleFormProject = useCallback(
        (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
            // console.log('ici => ', e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)
            setFormData({
                id: foldersList.length + 1,
                color: "ff7c03",
                transcriptions: [],
                jobs: [],
                isActive: false,
                ...formData,
                [e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget.value,
            });
            console.log(formData)
        }, [formData])

    const handleSubmitProject = (e: React.FormEvent, formData: Folders | {}) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        addProject(formData as Folders)
    }

    {
        return (
            <div className="dashboard__page">
                <Sidemenu/>
                <Outlet context={{ foldersList , isActiveFolder, isActiveSub, isActiveJob, isActiveCheckbox, counterJobs, toggle, handleModalContent }}/>
                <Modal
                    isShown={isShown}
                    hide={toggle}
                    headerText='Ajouter un projet'
                    modalContent={
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <form>
                                <label><input onChange={handleFormProject} type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nom du projet" /></label>
                                <div className="btn">
                                    <button className="btn__cancel" type="button" onClick={toggle}>Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit"
                                        onClick={(e) => {
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            handleSubmitProject(e, formData);
                                            toggle();
                                        }}
                                        >Add new folder
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export function useFoldersContext() {
    return useOutletContext<DataContextType>()
}
```

Folder.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { NavLink, useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { MdAddBox, MdChevronRight, MdPlayArrow } from "react-icons/md"
import { Checkbox } from "../../../components/Checkbox"
import { Chart } from "../../Dashboard/Chart"
import { useFoldersContext } from "../../Dashboard"
import './styles.scss'

// type
export type Folders = {
    id: number,
    color: string,
    name: string,
    transcriptions: string[],
    subfolders : Subfolder[],
    isActive: boolean
}
export type Subfolder = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    isActive: boolean,
    isChecked: boolean,
    jobs: Jobs[]
}
export type Jobs = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    isActive: boolean,
    isChecked: boolean
}

export function Folders() {

    const {folderId, subId, jobId } = useParams();

    const { foldersList, isActiveFolder, isActiveSub, isActiveJob, isActiveCheckbox, toggle, handleModalContent } = useFoldersContext()

    const slugify = (text: string | undefined ) => {
        if(text){
            text
                .toString()
                .normalize('NFD')
                .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
                .toLowerCase()
                .trim()
                .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
                .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '')
                .replace(/--+/g, '-')
        }
    }
    console.log(nanoid());

    const filetest = foldersList.map(({ id, name, subfolders }) => 
        <div key={id}>
            <NavLink key={id} to={`/dashboard/folders/${id}`}
                onClick={() => isActiveFolder(id)}
                className={({ isActive }) => {
                return isActive ? 
                "folder__item active" 
                :
                "folder__item";
            }}>
                <div className="content">
                    <MdPlayArrow className="icon"/>
                    <div className="title">{name}</div>
                </div>
            </NavLink>
            <div>
                {
                    folderId && ( id === parseInt(folderId) ?
                        subfolders.map( (subfolder: Subfolder) => (
                            <div key={subfolder.id} className="files__item">
                                <NavLink key={subfolder.id}to={`/dashboard/folders/${id}/subs/${subfolder.id}`}
                                    onClick={() => isActiveSub()}
                                    className={({ isActive }) => {
                                        return isActive ? "active" : "";
                                    }}>{subfolder.name}
                                </NavLink>
                            </div>
                        ))
                        : null 
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )


    return (
        <>
            <div className="folders__menu">
                <div className="folders__menu__container">
                    <div className="header">
                        <h2 className="title">{ foldersList.length > 0 ? `(${foldersList.length}) Projects` : 'Projects'}</h2>
                        <button id="folder" onClick={(e) => { 
                            e.stopPropagation()
                            toggle()
                            handleModalContent(e.currentTarget.id)
                        }}>
                            <MdAddBox className="icon"/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="folders__navigation">
                        {
                            filetest
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="files__menu">
                <div className="header">
                    {/*
                    <h2 className="title">{`(${counterJobs(foldersList)}) jobs`}</h2>
                    */}
                    <button>
                        <MdAddBox className="icon"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                {/*
                <div className="loading">
                    <div className="progress"></div>
                </div>
                */}
                <div className="files__navigation">
                    { foldersList.map( (folder: Folders) => (
                            folderId && ( folder.id === parseInt(folderId) ?
                                folder.subfolders.map( subfolder => (
                                        subId && ( subfolder.id === parseInt(subId) ?
                                            subfolder.jobs.map( job => (
                                                <li key={job.id} className="files__item">
                                                    <Checkbox onToggleCheckbox={() => isActiveCheckbox(job.id) } isChecked={job.isChecked} id={job.id} />
                                                    <NavLink key={job.id} to={`/dashboard/folders/${folder.id}/subs/${subfolder.id}/jobs/${job.id}`}
                                                        onClick={() => isActiveJob(job.id)}
                                                        className={({ isActive }) => {
                                                            return isActive ? "active" : "";
                                                        }}>{job.name}
                                                    </NavLink>
                                                    <MdChevronRight/>
                                                </li>
                                            ))
                                            : <></>
                                        )
                                    ))
                                : <></> 
                            )
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="menu__board">

                    {// un dossier et un job sélectionné
                        (folderId && jobId) && (
                            <div key={nanoid()} className="content">
                                <div className="content__info">
                                    <h1>Dans le jobs : {jobId} du dossier : {folderId}</h1>
                                </div>
                                <Chart />
                            </div>
                    )}

                     {// seulement un dossier sélectionné
                        (folderId && !jobId) && (
                            <div key={nanoid()} className="content">
                                <div className="content__info">
                                    <h1>Sélectionné un job ou créer en un : {`dossier : ${folderId}`}</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    )}

                    {// sans dossier et sans job sélectionné
                        !folderId && (
                            <div key={nanoid()} className="content">
                                <img src="\img\empty_file.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div className="content__info">
                                    <h1>Aucun fichier pour l’instant</h1>
                                    {/*
                                    <p>Un fichier est en cours de retranscription vous pourrez bientôt démarer l’analyse de ce test</p>
                                    */}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

and the log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKHW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l81Mx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hFlk.png)

I want to create a side menu with dropdowns using React and React DOM 6.4 in the best possible way with functional programming and hooks. If you have any examples or tutorials, I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

[EDIT SOLUTION]

I save my probleme with that change => remove conditionnal rendering + ternary on my boucle of maps(). Use filter() before map() and save only conditionnal rendering..

```
const projectsNavigation = foldersList
    .map((folder: Folders) => 
        <div key={`folders:${folder.id}`}>
            <NavLink to={`/dashboard/folders/${folder.id}`}
                onClick={() => isActiveFolder(folder.id)}
                className={({ isActive }) => {
                return isActive ? 
                "folder__item active" 
                :
                "folder__item";
            }}>
                <div className="content">
                    <MdPlayArrow className="icon"/>
                    <div className="title">{folder.name}</div>
                </div>
            </NavLink>
            <div>
            { 
                (folder.isActive && folderId) &&
                    folder.subfolders
                    .map( (subfolder: Subfolder) => (
                        <div key={`${folder.id}.${subfolder.id}`} className="files__item">
                            <NavLink to={`/dashboard/folders/${folder.id}/subs/${subfolder.id}`}
                                onClick={() => isActiveSub()}
                                className={({ isActive }) => {
                                    return isActive ? "active" : "";
                                }}>{subfolder.name}
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    )
                )
            }
            </div>
        </div>
)

const jobsNavigation = foldersList
    .filter( (folder: Folders) => folder.id === parseInt(folderId))
    .map( (folder: Folders) => (
        folder.subfolders
            .filter( subfolder => subfolder.id === parseInt(subId))
            .map( subfolder => (
                subfolder.jobs
                    .map( job => (
                        <li key={`${folder.id}.${subfolder.id}.${job.id}`} className="files__item">
                            <Checkbox onToggleCheckbox={() => isActiveCheckbox(job.id) } isChecked={job.isChecked} id={job.id} />
                            <NavLink to={`/dashboard/folders/${folder.id}/subs/${subfolder.id}/jobs/${job.id}`}
                                onClick={() => isActiveJob(job.id)}
                                className={({ isActive }) => {
                                    return isActive ? "active" : "";
                                }}>{job.name}
                            </NavLink>
                            <MdChevronRight/>
                        </li>
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The job ids are the same within the two subfolder objects (job ids 1 and 2). This will render <li> elements with the duplicate ids. Change this line `<li key={job.id} className="files__item">` to `<li key={\`${folder.id}.${subfolder.id}.${job.id}\`} className="files__item">` on Folder.tsx and that would remove the error on console.

Comment: I made the modification but it did not fix my error, but I understand the idea behind it and I had not thought about having identical keys! I thought that React was smart enough to differentiate between the different elements of the DOM since the generated elements are located in different parts of the tree.